# What is correct way to cast/convert array of objects to the parent interface the objects' interface extends in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have

```
interface IItemId {
   id: number;
   classId: number;
}

interface IItem extends IItemId {
   longString: string;
   anotherLongString: string
}

interface IAnotherItem extends IItemId {
   shortString: string;
   anotherShortString: string
}
```

Now I got method

```
sendItemIdsOveBroadcastChannel(itemIds: IItemId[]) {
   // add itemIds to broadcastchannel message
}
```

I want to call this with array of any kind of IItemId. But that results broadcastchannel message to be really large when there's lots of items.

I can do:

```
sendItemIdsOveBroadcastChannel(itemIds: IItemId[]) {
   const ids = itemIds.map(obj => { obj.id, obj.classId });
   // add ids to broadcastchannel message
}
```

but then I iterate over the array every time and create bunch of new objects even if the method was called with IItemId[] and not array of objects that extend the IItemId interface.

Another option is to map array before calling only when the objects are of extended type. However that's not clean.

Is there any better solution for this?

Comment: To clarify, your concern is just about the size of the message, right? TypeScript won't offer any solution there, since casting an object to a base type doesn't actually discard data at runtime. You'll be looking at the same range of approaches that are available in plain JS.

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```
private getBaseObjects(items: IItemId []): IItemId [] {
  if (items.length > 0 && Object.keys(items[0]).length > 2) {
    return items.map(item => { 
      return { id: item.id, tableId: item.classId }
    });
  }
  return items;
}

sendItemIdsOveBroadcastChannel(itemIds: IItemId[]) {
   const ids = this.getBaseObjects(itemIds);
   // add ids to broadcastchannel message
}
```

So instead of just converting always the array with map, I check the item type.
Probably just converting would be good enough. It's not 200k items in array ever and even 20k is rare.